# GDB. Catch only not caught exceptions

Tags: c++, c, gdb

Catching like this, **using GDB**:

```
catch throw
```

When exception is thrown, the program stops.

How to make GDB not stop when exception is thrown but is caught by the program ?
Or should I have global try-catch and not **using GDB**

```
catch throw
```

?

**EDIT1**

```
try
{
  // every time exception is thrown
  // program is stopped by GDB
}
catch(const std::exception &e)
{
  // even if the exception is caught by the program
}
```

**EDIT2** starting gdb

```
gdb
file /usr/home/user/program
shell ps x
attach #pid
catch throw
c
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean? Or at least post some complete code?

Comment: You are not using GDB **catch throw**

Comment: It's hard to understand that the `catch throw` part is the GDB command. I suggest you rephrase such as "When using the command `catch throw` in GDB, ..."

Comment: sorry for misleading please. EDIT2 for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`catch throw` will catch all thrown exceptions and there isn't a way to restrict that.

You have at least two options here. You could just not use `catch throw` at all, and if you're on some flavor of unix, it will seg fault and stop at the point the exception is thrown, if it won't be caught.

Alternately you could set a breakpoint on `__raise_exception` as seen at ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_30.html (which was the first hit when I used google - please try to research yourself before posting on Stackoverflow).

Comment: When catching nothing would it be possible to see backtrace on segfault ?

Comment: Yes, gdb should show you the backtrace at the throwing point if you don't catch the exception.